# c#: deserialize unknown xml elements to an array or list

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

Given the following XML:

```
<browser>
    <firefox company="mozilla"></firefox>
    <chrome company="google"></chrome>
    <ie company="microsoft"></ie>     
</browser>
```

This is my code for deserializing:

```
[XmlRoot("browser")]
public class Browser
{
    //--List or Array
    List<BrowserType> browserTypes {get; set;}
}

public class BrowserType
{
    [XmlAttribute("company")]
    public string company {get; set;}
}

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Browser));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("browser.xml");
Browser browser = (Browser )xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);

foreach(var item in browserTypes)
{
    //--List browser types 
}
```

For this problem, I cannot do the following code for the XmlArrayItem since I do not know the element name.

```
[XmlArray("browser")]
[XmlArrayItem("firefox")]
public BrowserType[] BrowserTypes{ get; set; }
```

How to deserialize unknown xml elements to an array or list?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Ok, so using xml serialization, you can specify a list of `BrowserType`s and then specify the `XmlElement` name and type for each of the derived types. Example:

```
[XmlRoot("browser")]
public class Browser
{
    private readonly List<BrowserType> _items = new List<BrowserType>();
    [XmlElement("firefox", typeof(Firefox))]
    [XmlElement("chrome", typeof(Chrome))]
    [XmlElement("ie", typeof(IE))]
    public List<BrowserType> Items { get { return _items; } }
}

public class BrowserType
{
    [XmlAttribute("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
}

public class Firefox : BrowserType
{
}

public class Chrome : BrowserType
{
}


public class IE : BrowserType
{
}
```

**Original Entry:**

If you can switch to `XDocument` instead, then you could grab all the descendants of the root node and then get the name of each descendant. Example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlString = @"<browser>
<firefox company=""mozilla""></firefox>
<chrome company=""google""></chrome>
<ie company=""microsoft""></ie>     
</browser>";

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var elementNames = xdoc.Root.Descendants()      // Get the descendants of the root node
                                    .Select(element => element.Name.LocalName);     // Project each XElement to its name
        string[] browserTypes = elementNames.ToArray();

        foreach (string browserType in browserTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(browserType);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
firefox
chrome
ie
```

Comment: yes i can get those elements using linq to xml. but what I'm trying to do here is to construct the classes based on the xml schema. i'm expecting to have something like [XmlArray("browser")]
[XmlArrayItem("firefox")]
public BrowserType[] BrowserTypes{ get; set; }

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. i can definitely do that. but just for clarification, at the point when i run the deserialization, the program has no knowledge of the elements. i mean firefox, chrome and ie are all unknown elements so i can't create classes for those and define the in the XElement's typeof(). is there any way i can dynamically set the XElement attribute. well i was able to do this with the XmlRoot element using new XmlRootAttribute("whatever root name u want") but not sure how to do it for the child elements.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't know how to do that. :) According to this [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23399551/4551527), you can use XmlDocument or XDocument (like in my original answer) or he also suggested using Json.NET (which I guess has XML support). Best of luck!